# Can I add a description for Ubercart catalog categories?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, ubercart

I am working on an Ubercart store with several products with a hierarchy of categories.

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a description at the top of the catalog page for each category?

I know that each category is a taxonomy term with which I can set its description, but I can't see any way of displaying that. I've also looked at the option of using a custom block and using a token in the block body but tokens don't seem to be recognised in the block's body.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the catalog view, enable a Global:Text area in the Header, and set the input filter to PHP code.

The following code will print the term description and any associated taxonomy image in the view header.

```
<?php
$view = views_get_current_view();
$tid = $view->args[0];
$description = "";

if ( is_numeric( $tid ) ) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

  $description = $description . "<div class='term-description'>";

  if (isset($term->uc_catalog_image['und'][0]['uri'] )) {
     $description = $description . "<img src='" . image_style_url( 'uc_product_list', $term->uc_catalog_image['und'][0]['uri']) . "' class='term-image' /> ";
  }  

  if (module_exists('i18n_taxonomy') && i18n_taxonomy_vocabulary_mode($term->vid) == I18N_MODE_LOCALIZE) {
    $description = $description . i18n_string("taxonomy:term:$term->tid:description", $term->description);
  } else {
    $description = $description . $term->description;
  }
  $description = $description . "</div>";
  print $description;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I've managed to create the global text area but how do I set the input filter to the PHP code?

Comment: Got it. I didn't have the PHP code filter module turned on.

Comment: Under the text input box you will find a dropdown list labelled 'Text Format'. One of the items will be PHP Code if you have that filter available. If not, enable the core module (PHP Filter) under /admin/modules, and make sure you have permission.